# English multiple choice question

Tags: grammar

The politician is reported ______ an affair with an actress two years ago.

(a) to have had
(b) to have
(c) that he had
(d) that he had had.

Can anyone explain to me why the answer is (a) but not the rest?

Comment: Hello, Muuu. [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-reported-to-be-do-something) shows  the 'be reported to be/do something' expression, together with an example similar to that in the question ('He is reported to have upbraided his commanders ...').  One needs say 'It as reported' to license a that-clause ('It as reported that the politician had an ...'). (c) and (d) are thus disallowed. The temporal phrase 'two years ago' forces the past construction, '[reported] to have had ...', disallowing (b).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is a particular pattern for forming the passive voice of verbs like "say" or "report" with reported speech:

Consider this active voice sentence.

> Somone says that John has gone shopping.

In the passive it could be

> That John has gone shopping is said. (by someone)

But English prefers to avoid such long, weighty subjects.  Instead a passive form is

> John is said to have gone shopping (by someone).

In this form, the subject of the embedded clause becomes the main subject, and the verb in the embedded clause is made into an infinitive.  This is one way that the passive voice of reported speech can be formed.

So, only a and b have a correct infinitive.  The perfective form of the infinitive "to have had" is used because the event "have an affair" is in the past and completed. It isn't ongoing.  So (a) is the only possible answer.

There are other possible passive forms, such as using a dummy subject "it". This form would preserve "that":

> It is reported that the politician had an affair with an actress two years ago.

Comment: A more likely passive form, keeping the finite subordinate clause, is _It is said that John has gone shopping_. But since the question had _the politician_ as subject, that is not possible in this case.